# how can i pass the parameter file in ansible cloud formation module

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am using the cloudformation module in ansible and I am facing issue in passing the parameter file.

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported
>   parameters for (cloudformation) module: dist Supported parameters
>   include: aws_access_key, aws_secret_key, backoff_delay,
>   backoff_max_delay, backoff_retries, capabilities, changeset_name,
>   create_changeset, create_timeout, debug_botocore_endpoint_logs,
>   disable_rollback, ec2_url, events_limit, notification_arns, profile,
>   region, role_arn, security_token, stack_name, stack_policy, state,
>   tags, template, template_body, template_format, template_parameters,
>   template_url, termination_protection, validate_certs"}

I have already use the template_parameters without dist attribute, as shown below,

```
#template_parameters: "{{ lookup('file', '/root/cloudformation_template/Parameter-tableau.json') | from_json }}"
```

But I am getting the same error. The task looks like the following task,

```
- name: create a cloudformation stack
  cloudformation:
        stack_name: "ansible-cloudformation111"
        state: "present"
        template: "/root/cloudformation_template/poc-tableau.json"
        template_parameters:
        dist: "{{ lookup('file', '/root/cloudformation_template/Parameter-tableau.json')  }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to say what the problem is since the code block in your question is not formatted, and formatting is very important in yaml and ansible. But I have a guess.

If your task is formatted like this

```
name: create a cloudformation stack
cloudformation:
  stack_name: "ansible-cloudformation111"
  state: "present"
  template: "/root/cloudformation_template/poc-tableau.json"
  template_parameters:
  dist: "{{ lookup('file', '/root/cloudformation_template/Parameter-tableau.json') }}"
```

then you'll get the error message `Unsupported parameters for (cloudformation) module: dist` because here `dist` is a parameter of `cloudformation` due to the formatting. Indenting the `dist` line by two more spaces should fix the issue:

```
name: create a cloudformation stack
cloudformation:
  stack_name: "ansible-cloudformation111"
  state: "present"
  template: "/root/cloudformation_template/poc-tableau.json"
  template_parameters:
    dist: "{{ lookup('file', '/root/cloudformation_template/Parameter-tableau.json') }}"
```

Comment: hi steingberg, thakyou for your answer

Comment: - hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: create a cloudformation stack
      cloudformation:
        stack_name: "ansible"
        state: "present"
        template: "/root/cloudformation_template/poc-tableau.json"
        template_parameters:
          dist: "{{ lookup('file', '/root/cloudformation_template/Parameter-tableau.json') | from_json }}"

Comment: must have values - <class 'botocore.exceptions.ClientError'>."}

Comment: i am trying to lanch a new instance in ansible using cloud formation module  i have the two files one is  cloudformation templeate file and parameter file both are in json files i am unable to pass the parameter file in the cloud formation module please suggest any solution how to pass the parameter fle in ansible

Comment: Hi. It sounds like the error that you originally posted about was fixed by using the correct indentation in your task, and now you are getting a new error message. Is that correct? If so, I recommend posting a new question. There, give some more details, including the contents of the two json files, the full playbook you are running, and the full error you are receiving.

Comment: my previous problem was not fixed still i am phasing the problem i am explain my problem